# How to add small bump like features (small Gaussian-like features) on this blue curve?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am making the following picture using the below code. I want to add some small 4-5 "bumps" (sort of like small Gaussian wavepackets) in the topmost quadrant on the blue curve like in this picture. The bumps should be a bit separated from each other, and should lie on the blue curve. [image]

The diagram I made till now is given below along with the code. How do I do that? [image: this picture]

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (I)    at ( 4,0)   {};
\node (II)   at (-4,0)   {};
\node (III)  at (0, 2.5) {};
\node (IV)   at (0,-2.5) {};

\path  
(II) +(90:4)  coordinate[label=90:]  (IItop)
   +(-90:4) coordinate[label=-90:] (IIbot)
   +(0:4)   coordinate                  (IIright)
   +(180:4) coordinate[label=180:] (IIleft);

\draw (IItop) --(IIright) -- (IIbot)--cycle;


\path 
(I) +(90:4)  coordinate (Itop)
   +(-90:4) coordinate (Ibot)
   +(180:4) coordinate (Ileft)
   +(0:4)   coordinate (Iright);


\draw  (Ileft) -- (Itop) -- (Ibot) -- (Ileft) -- cycle;

% Squiggly lines
\draw[decorate,decoration=zigzag, red, thick] (IItop) -- (Itop)
  node[midway, above, inner sep=2mm] {};

\draw[decorate,decoration=zigzag, red, thick] (IIbot) -- (Ibot)
  node[midway, below, inner sep=2mm] {};

\draw[blue, thick]   % The -> adds an arrow tip
($(Itop)!.07!(Ibot)$) to[out=220, in=-40, looseness=1.3] ($(IItop)!.07!(IIbot)$);




\draw[fill] ($(Itop)!.07!(Ibot)$) circle [radius=0.05] node[right] {$t$};

\draw[fill] ($(IItop)!.07!(IIbot)$) circle [radius=0.05] node[left] {$t$};


\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your example complete instead of posting sniplets where others have to guess a suitable preamble and document class.

Comment: @daleif Done, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The perhaps simplest way to add Gaussians is to add Gaussians. That is, find an analytic curve that reproduces your blue curve, and add Gaussians.

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={gauss(\x)=(abs(\x)<2 ? exp(-5*\x*\x):0);}]
\node (I)    at ( 4,0)   {};
\node (II)   at (-4,0)   {};
\node (III)  at (0, 2.5) {};
\node (IV)   at (0,-2.5) {};

\path  
(II) +(90:4)  coordinate[label=90:]  (IItop)
   +(-90:4) coordinate[label=-90:] (IIbot)
   +(0:4)   coordinate                  (IIright)
   +(180:4) coordinate[label=180:] (IIleft);

\draw (IItop) --(IIright) -- (IIbot)--cycle;


\path 
(I) +(90:4)  coordinate (Itop)
   +(-90:4) coordinate (Ibot)
   +(180:4) coordinate (Ileft)
   +(0:4)   coordinate (Iright);


\draw  (Ileft) -- (Itop) -- (Ibot) -- (Ileft) -- cycle;

% Squiggly lines
\draw[decorate,decoration=zigzag, red, thick] (IItop) -- (Itop)
  node[midway, above, inner sep=2mm] {};

\draw[decorate,decoration=zigzag, red, thick] (IIbot) -- (Ibot)
  node[midway, below, inner sep=2mm] {};

% \draw[blue, thick]   % The -> adds an arrow tip
% ($(Itop)!.07!(Ibot)$) to[out=220, in=-40, looseness=1.3] ($(IItop)!.07!(IIbot)$);

\draw[blue, thick] plot[variable=\t,domain=-4:4,samples=101] 
(\t,{1.48+\t*\t/8+0.5*gauss(\t-3)+0.5*gauss(\t-1)+0.5*gauss(\t+1)+0.5*gauss(\t+3)});


\draw[fill] ($(Itop)!.07!(Ibot)$) circle [radius=0.05] node[right] {$t$};

\draw[fill] ($(IItop)!.07!(IIbot)$) circle [radius=0.05] node[left] {$t$};


\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

As for your comment:

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={gauss(\x)=(abs(\x)<2 ? exp(-10*\x*\x):0);}]
\node (I)    at ( 4,0)   {};
\node (II)   at (-4,0)   {};
\node (III)  at (0, 2.5) {};
\node (IV)   at (0,-2.5) {};

\path  
(II) +(90:4)  coordinate[label=90:]  (IItop)
   +(-90:4) coordinate[label=-90:] (IIbot)
   +(0:4)   coordinate                  (IIright)
   +(180:4) coordinate[label=180:] (IIleft);

\draw (IItop) --(IIright) -- (IIbot)--cycle;


\path 
(I) +(90:4)  coordinate (Itop)
   +(-90:4) coordinate (Ibot)
   +(180:4) coordinate (Ileft)
   +(0:4)   coordinate (Iright);


\draw  (Ileft) -- (Itop) -- (Ibot) -- (Ileft) -- cycle;

% Squiggly lines
\draw[decorate,decoration=zigzag, red, thick] (IItop) -- (Itop)
  node[midway, above, inner sep=2mm] {};

\draw[decorate,decoration=zigzag, red, thick] (IIbot) -- (Ibot)
  node[midway, below, inner sep=2mm] {};

\draw[blue, thick]   % The -> adds an arrow tip
($(Itop)!.07!(Ibot)$) to[out=220, in=-40, looseness=1.3] ($(IItop)!.07!(IIbot)$);

\draw[red, thick] foreach \X in {-3,-1,1,3}
{plot[variable=\t,domain=\X-0.8:\X+0.8,samples=31] 
(\t,{1.48+\t*\t/6.8-\t*\t*\t*\t/640+0.5*gauss(\t-3)+0.5*gauss(\t-1)+0.5*gauss(\t+1)+0.5*gauss(\t+3)})};


\draw[fill] ($(Itop)!.07!(Ibot)$) circle [radius=0.05] node[right] {$t$};

\draw[fill] ($(IItop)!.07!(IIbot)$) circle [radius=0.05] node[left] {$t$};


\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or just add them via nodes (the `\savebox` saves some compilation time, otherwise a `pic` also works).

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newsavebox\Gaussian
\sbox\Gaussian{\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={
    gauss(\x)=(abs(\x)<2 ? exp(-15*\x*\x):0);}]
 \draw[red,thick] plot[smooth,domain=-0.8:0.8] (\x,{0.5*gauss(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (I)    at ( 4,0)   {};
\node (II)   at (-4,0)   {};
\node (III)  at (0, 2.5) {};
\node (IV)   at (0,-2.5) {};

\path  
(II) +(90:4)  coordinate[label=90:]  (IItop)
   +(-90:4) coordinate[label=-90:] (IIbot)
   +(0:4)   coordinate                  (IIright)
   +(180:4) coordinate[label=180:] (IIleft);

\draw (IItop) --(IIright) -- (IIbot)--cycle;


\path 
(I) +(90:4)  coordinate (Itop)
   +(-90:4) coordinate (Ibot)
   +(180:4) coordinate (Ileft)
   +(0:4)   coordinate (Iright);


\draw  (Ileft) -- (Itop) -- (Ibot) -- (Ileft) -- cycle;

% Squiggly lines
\draw[decorate,decoration=zigzag, red, thick] (IItop) -- (Itop)
  node[midway, above, inner sep=2mm] {};

\draw[decorate,decoration=zigzag, red, thick] (IIbot) -- (Ibot)
  node[midway, below, inner sep=2mm] {};

\draw[blue, thick]   % The -> adds an arrow tip
($(Itop)!.07!(Ibot)$) to[out=220, in=-40, looseness=1.3] 
node[pos=0.1,sloped,above=-3pt]{\usebox\Gaussian}
node[pos=0.35,sloped,above=-2pt]{\usebox\Gaussian}
node[pos=0.65,sloped,above=-2pt]{\usebox\Gaussian}
node[pos=0.9,sloped,above=-3pt]{\usebox\Gaussian}
($(IItop)!.07!(IIbot)$);

\draw[fill] ($(Itop)!.07!(Ibot)$) circle [radius=0.05] node[right] {$t$};

\draw[fill] ($(IItop)!.07!(IIbot)$) circle [radius=0.05] node[left] {$t$};


\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, however I want to add extra "Gaussian-wavepacket" like features on top of the blue curve, say with red colour.

Comment: @BruceLee I added something but I do not quite understand what "I want to add extra Gaussian features on top of the blue curve, say with red colour" is supposed to mean.

Comment: I see, let me post a pic and add the same to the question, it will be helpful.

Comment: Hi, I edited the question to include a picture. Basically I want the 4-5 wavepackets to be a bit separated, and lying on the blue line. Thanks.

Comment: @BruceLee I added two ways of achieving something of that sort.

Comment: Hi this is great, thanks. :)  what should I do in order to decrease the size of the Gaussians?

Comment: In the code you see things like `0.5*gauss`, if you decrease the prefactor `0.5`, this will reduce the height. If you increase `15` in `exp(-15*\x*\x)`, the width will decrease.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was extremely helpful.